# How can I resolve that IndexOutOfBound Exception?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I've got a problem with my Code. Whatever I do , I receive an IndexOutOfBoundException at the line with the if-statement. I've already tried everything. 
The programm should usually check the values of the indices always at the first and at the last position of an integer-Array. If the values are equal it's gonna be outprinted, if they aren't equal,too.
Thanks for your help!

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int[]test = new int[] {3,4,5,5,4,3};
    IntSym(test);
    System.out.println(test.length);

}

public static void IntSym(int[]test) {
    for(int j=0; j<=test.length/2;j++) {
        if(test[j]==test[test.length-j]) {
            System.out.println(j+"."+ (test.length-j) +". are equal");
        }else{
            System.out.println(j+"."+ (test.length-j) +". aren't equal");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What value of `j` does it fail for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first iteration since `j=0` then `test[test.length-j]` will throw the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

To solve the problem replace it with `test[test.length-j-1]`:

```
public static void IntSym(int[]test) {
    for(int j=0; j<=test.length/2;j++) {
        if(test[j]==test[test.length-j-1]) {
            System.out.println(j+"."+ (test.length-j) +". are equal");
        }else{
            System.out.println(j+"."+ (test.length-j) +". aren't equal");
        }
    }
}
```